# How to play .m4a in Clementine?

Tags: gstreamer, clementine

Clementine says missing gstreamer plugin when I try to play a .m4a file. Totem and Rhythm Box play it fine.

```
$ wajig listinstalled gstreamer0.10
gstreamer0.10-alsa:amd64
gstreamer0.10-nice:amd64
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:amd64
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:amd64
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:amd64
gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:amd64
gstreamer0.10-x:amd64
libgstreamer0.10-0:amd64
```

I'm on Trusty, Clementine was great on Precise, so keen to get it working again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to install `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`, and possibly remove your `~/.gstreamer-0.10/` folder, which is in your user's directory

Comment: Thanks! The package is called `gstreamer-plugins-bad` on Fedora.

Comment: Not working on ubuntu 15.04

Comment: After installing the 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' package on my Ubuntu 14.04 I only had to restart Clementine.  Fiddling with the $HOME/.gstreamer-0.10/ folder was not necessary in my case.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 you need to install `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`.

Answer (score 5):

There are missing multimedia extras plugins on your system

The fix that worked for me was running:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: You also need to restart Clementine! (with Ctrl+Q to quit)

Answer (score 0):

In my case `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` had already been installed but I still couldn't play m4a-files.

After installing `1.3.2 rc1` for Trusty (Ubuntu 14.04) from https://builds.clementine-player.org/ it worked.

Comment: Same case for me, plugin was installed and this upgrade helped, thank you!